# Recieve HighStock RangeSelector button event in Angular 2+ component

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I want to access highstock rangeSelector button event inside my angular component.I am using the `angular2-highcharts` package to use the highcharts library. Tried to access it using the `(afterSetExtremes)` binding but without any success. The code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OwcqjORHCB9pZHBrt4cm?p=preview). Please help.

Thanks!!

Comment: I see that in your demo you use `rangeSelector.buttons[index].events.click` property. Isn't applying it to all the buttons the solution that you're looking for (http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/qq8uzs6a/)? Or maybe you want to catch some events other then click?

Comment: Actually I put it there to test but, I am not able to get it work event the one where I have put it.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. `rangeSelector.buttons[index].events.click` works fine in pure Highcharts (http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/7c092cha/) but it doesn't when using the wrapper: (http://plnkr.co/edit/byYtdXJBzRR2eAeS8CiZ?p=preview). **angular2-highcharts** is not an official Highcharts wrapper so you should inform its creator about this issue or report it on github.

Comment: Yeah will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your template as

```
template: `
  <chart type="StockChart" [options]="options" (click)="onClick($event)">
  </chart>
`,
```

function

```
onClick(e) {
  console.log('You clicked '+e.toElement.innerHTML+" button")
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/trKdfhoyGLHgJR786zNl?p=preview) demo

Comment: thanks for the comment but, it looks little hackish. I was hoping to tap the events provided by highchart.js library.

Comment: It's not hackish as you say check [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#chart-events) how event are captured. If you want to do that in highcharts js then use it's npm not angular2 highcharts npm

Comment: ohkk, I will try this out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check [TypeScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts#typescript) highcharts version installation  and implementation below.

[stackblitz](https://highstock-angular-cli.stackblitz.io/) Demo

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import { Jsonp, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5 Highstock';
  @ViewChild("container", { read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;

  constructor(jsonp: Jsonp) {
    jsonp.request('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe(res => {


      Highcharts.stockChart(this.container.nativeElement, {
        rangeSelector: {
          buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m',
            events: {
              click: function (e) {
                console.log('button clickd');
              }
            }
          }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 3,
            text: '3m'
          }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 6,
            text: '6m'
          }, {
            type: 'ytd',
            text: 'YTD'
          }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
          }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All1'
          }]
        },
        chart: {
          zoomType: 'x'
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'AAPL',
          data: res.json(),
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
          }
        }],
        xAxis: {
          events: {
            afterSetExtremes: (e) => {
              // console.log(e);
              // this.button = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;

            }
          }
        },
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi check this is according to highcharts npm version