# Highcharts load even is not firing in angular 4 with columnrange chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Load event in Highcharts is not firing, the [same code](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcLeeyz/32/) is working with javascript but when I move it to angular its not working. Can anybody please help.

Html Code snippet
`<chart [options]="dwellTimePerZoneOptions"></chart>`

**Typescript Code snippet:**

```
    let yThreshold = 25;
    this.dwellTimePerZoneOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true,
            width: this.chartWidth,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    debugger;
                    var series = this.series[0],
                        points = series.points,
                        newPoints = [];

                    points.forEach((point) => {

                        // add x value to options
                        point.options.x = point.x;

                        // original values are used in tooltip and data labels formatter
                        point.options.originalLow = point.low;
                        point.options.originalHigh = point.high;


                        if (point.low < yThreshold && point.high > yThreshold) {

                            // split the point
                            newPoints.push($.extend({}, point.options, {
                                low: point.low,
                                high: yThreshold,
                                partOfSplitPoint: 'bottom'
                            }), $.extend({}, point.options, {
                                low: yThreshold,
                                high: point.high,
                                partOfSplitPoint: 'top'
                            }));

                        } else {
                            // splitting not needed - just pass original options
                            newPoints.push(point.options);
                        }
                    });

                    // color the points
                    newPoints.forEach(function (pointOptions) {
                        if (pointOptions.high <= yThreshold) {
                            pointOptions.color = 'green';
                        } else {
                            pointOptions.color = 'red';
                        }
                    });

                    series.setData(newPoints, false);

                    // new data label will show up after the redraw
                    this.redraw();
                }
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Dwell Time Per Zone'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Building C, New York, USA'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Zone A', 'Zone B', 'Zone C', 'Zone D', 'Dock Zone', 'Stage Zone']
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Min & Max Time ( Hrs )'
            }
        },


        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Dwell Time (hrs)',
            data: [
                [0.5, 22.6],
                [2.9, 29.5],
                [9.2, 30.7],
                [7.3, 26.5],
                [4.4, 18.0],
                [3.5, 9.8]
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    var point = this.point;
                    switch (this.y) {
                        case point.originalLow:
                            return point.originalLow;
                        case point.originalHigh:
                            return point.originalHigh;
                        default:
                            return point.partOfSplitPoint ? null : point.y;
                    }
                }
            }
        }],

        tooltip: {
            followPointer: true,
            pointFormatter: function () {
                return "<span style='color:{" + this.color + "}'>\u25CF</span> " + this.series.name + ": <b>" + this.originalLow + " - " + this.originalHigh + "</b><br/>"
            }
        }
    };
```

While debugging I found that load function inside event is not getting called. I am not able to figure out what I am missing, can anybody please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use official [npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) it will work

Comment: I am using official package only..however its not working..

Comment: Can you update you post with stackblitz demo

Comment: I have observed one thing, that is if I am using rendering the chart with below code:

    `Highcharts.chart('dwellTimePerZone', {
         //options
    });`

buts its not working with 

   `<chart [options]="dwellTimePerZoneOptions"></chart>`

What can be reason behind this?

Comment: hi check this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47917119/3898339) using third party wrapper and official npm package.